# Spark: update a Dataframe based on a join operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that is being up to date each date.
Each day i need to add the new qte and the new ca to the old one and update the date. 
So I need to update the ones that are already existing and add the new ones.

Here an example what i would like to have at the end:

```
val histocaisse = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
      .load("C:/Users/MHT/Desktop/histocaisse_dte1.csv")

    val hist = histocaisse
      .withColumn("pos_id", 'pos_id.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("article_id", 'pos_id.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("date", 'date.cast(DateType))
      .withColumn("qte", 'qte.cast(DoubleType))
      .withColumn("ca", 'ca.cast(DoubleType))



    val histocaisse2 = spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true") //reading the headers

      .load("C:/Users/MHT/Desktop/histocaisse_dte2.csv")

    val hist2 = histocaisse2.withColumn("pos_id", 'pos_id.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("article_id", 'pos_id.cast(LongType))
      .withColumn("date", 'date.cast(DateType))
      .withColumn("qte", 'qte.cast(DoubleType))
      .withColumn("ca", 'ca.cast(DoubleType))
    hist2.show(false)

+------+----------+----------+----+----+
|pos_id|article_id|date      |qte |ca  |
+------+----------+----------+----+----+
|1     |1         |2000-01-07|2.5 |3.5 |
|2     |2         |2000-01-07|14.7|12.0|
|3     |3         |2000-01-07|3.5 |1.2 |
+------+----------+----------+----+----+

+------+----------+----------+----+----+
|pos_id|article_id|date      |qte |ca  |
+------+----------+----------+----+----+
|1     |1         |2000-01-08|2.5 |3.5 |
|2     |2         |2000-01-08|14.7|12.0|
|3     |3         |2000-01-08|3.5 |1.2 |
|4     |4         |2000-01-08|3.5 |1.2 |
|5     |5         |2000-01-08|14.5|1.2 |
|6     |6         |2000-01-08|2.0 |1.25|
+------+----------+----------+----+----+

+------+----------+----------+----+----+
|pos_id|article_id|date      |qte |ca  |
+------+----------+----------+----+----+
|1     |1         |2000-01-08|5.0 |7.0 |
|2     |2         |2000-01-08|39.4|24.0|
|3     |3         |2000-01-08|7.0 |2.4 |
|4     |4         |2000-01-08|3.5 |1.2 |
|5     |5         |2000-01-08|14.5|1.2 |
|6     |6         |2000-01-08|2.0 |1.25|
+------+----------+----------+----+----+
```

To do so i did this

```
val df = hist2.join(hist1, Seq("article_id", "pos_id"), "left")
  .select($"pos_id", $"article_id",
    coalesce(hist2("date"), hist1("date")).alias("date"),
    (coalesce(hist2("qte"), lit(0)) + coalesce(hist1("qte"), lit(0))).alias("qte"),
    (coalesce(hist2("ca"), lit(0)) + coalesce(hist1("ca"), lit(0))).alias("ca"))
  .orderBy("pos_id", "article_id")

// df.show()
|pos_id|article_id|      date| qte|  ca|
+------+----------+----------+----+----+
|     1|         1|2000-01-08| 5.0| 7.0|
|     2|         2|2000-01-08|29.4|24.0|
|     3|         3|2000-01-08| 7.0| 2.4|
|     4|         4|2000-01-08| 3.5| 1.2|
|     5|         5|2000-01-08|14.5| 1.2|
|     6|         6|2000-01-08| 2.0|1.25|
+------+----------+----------+----+----+
```

The goal is to update infos if there are existing and to add new ones .But when i tried the case hist is empty i got the following issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1321)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
```

what should i do to take into consideration even the case where the first table is empty

Comment: Does `histocaisse_dte1.csv` have a header line?

Answer (score 0):

For that you should define a `schema` and apply it when you are reading the csv files. By doing that you don't even need the casting codes. :)

In your case both dataframes looks the same so you can create schema as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("pos_id", LongType, true),
  StructField("article_id", LongType, true),
  StructField("date", DateType, true),
  StructField("qte", LongType, true),
  StructField("ca", DoubleType, true)
))
```

then you can use the `schema` as

```
val hist1 = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
  .schema(schema)
  .load("C:/Users/MHT/Desktop/histocaisse_dte1.csv")

val hist2 = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
  .schema(schema)
  .load("C:/Users/MHT/Desktop/histocaisse_dte2.csv")
```

Then finally you can apply the final logic without errors

Answer (score 0):

Databricks Spark runtime supports MERGE operator

which allows you to update target tables based on join condition

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/merge-into.html

```sql
MERGE INTO [db_name.]target_table [AS target_alias]
USING [db_name.]source_table [<time_travel_version>] [AS source_alias]
ON <merge_condition>
[ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <condition> ] THEN <matched_action> ]
[ WHEN MATCHED [ AND <condition> ] THEN <matched_action> ]
[ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ AND <condition> ]  THEN <not_matched_action> ]
```

Basically it'll be a merge with update only clause